# К чему это относится ?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Подскажите, к каким предметам имеет отношение размерность "4 см." в данном предложении.

Хворостом являются срезанные тонкие стволы деревьев диаметром в комле до 4 см, а также срезанные вершины, сучья и ветви деревьев.

Comment: Если вам ответ понравился, у вас есть возможность поставить лайк (палец вверх слева от ответа) или выбрать его как верный (галочка слева от ответа). Награду баллами приберегите до более высокого рейтинга.

Answer (score 5):

К стволам деревьев. Для остальных предметов ограничения в тексте не указаны.

Answer (score 2):

Хороший вопрос на самом деле.
Юридически формулировка может быть оспорена, поскольку тут грамматическая некорректность, ну или как минимум двусмысленность. Относится ли "4 см" только к комлю ("комель" здесь понимается как место отпила, реже - сруба). Поэтому, не привлекая "внешних соображений", трудно дать ответ на Ваш вопрос.    
Но если до суда не дойдет, то можно с большой долей уверенности сказать, что речь идет о ***максимальном*** диаметре ствола, он же - диаметр в комле, поскольку стволы деревьев в естественных условиях внизу шире, чем наверху. Поэтому понятие "в комле" используется в профессиональной речи для указания максимального диаметра. 
Так что если вопрос в этом - не заморачивайтесь.
Касательно применимости "4 см" к срезанным веткам и прочему - вопрос так, думаю, не стоит. Ни по построению фразы грамматике предложения, ни по сути - комля у них нет.

Comment: Спасибо всем ответившим.
"Спор" возник именно о  применимости "4 см" к срезанным веткам и прочему.
Просто мне необходимо было стороннее подтверждение моей правоты, что я от вас и получил.
Еще раз спасибо.
Вопросов больше не имею. ПОКА не имею.

Comment: А как мотивируют применимость к веткам?!

Comment: Я ему показываю текст, он читает... долго думает.
Потом заявляет: "А нам так всегда начальник говорил, что "4 см." относится ко всему перечисленому".

Comment: Вообще-то,  хворост  диаметром  10-15  см  трудно  представить.  Может  такие  дрова  ещё  как-нибудь  называются ?